# What is the solution to 13th part of 'select from world' tutorial on sqlzoo?

Tags: sql, case, sql-like, case-when

The [problem statement](http://sqlzoo.net/wiki/SELECT_from_WORLD_Tutorial) is:

> Put the continents right...
>
> - Oceania becomes Australasia
> - Countries in Eurasia and Turkey go to Europe/Asia
> - Caribbean islands starting with 'B' go to North America, other Caribbean islands go to South America
>
> Show the name, the original continent and the new continent of all
>   countries.

My solution:

```
SELECT name, continent,
   CASE WHEN continent='Oceania' THEN 'Australasia'
        WHEN continent IN ('Europe', 'Asia') THEN 'Europe/Asia'
        WHEN name='Turkey' THEN 'Europe/Asia'
        WHEN continent='Caribbean' AND name LIKE 'B%' THEN 'North America'
        WHEN continent='Caribbean' AND name NOT LIKE 'B%' THEN 'South America'
        ELSE continent END
FROM world
```

The result I get from sqlzoo is "Wrong answer. Some of the data is incorrect.".

Comment: The question says `Eurasia`, your answer says `IN ('Europe', 'Asia')`. Personally, I didn't think Turkey contained any countries.

Comment: I agree with @jodrell (trying to predict what sqlzoo anticipates as a correct answer...) The good news is that your SQL is 100% solid and the issue is with the strings you've stuck in there that sqlzoo doesn't like.

Comment: @Jodrell, I tried that now, but it also does not work. The original table is not supposed to contain 'Eurasia' in the continent column.

Comment: I suspect the specification is ambiguous, hence the confusion.

Comment: @Jodrell, agreed. I will contact the admins on sqlzoo.

Comment: Since the question seem to be progressive, you should show a working answer to question 12.

Comment: @systemovich: It does contain Eurasia though. Try this to see them: `SELECT name, continent
FROM world
where continent='Eurasia'`

Comment: @clesiemo3, I see. I thought it would not, based on question 12.

Comment: @systemovich: The site seems to be a little squirrely in some things. Questions aren't super clear and the order by bug mentioned in answers below. On the plus side, your sql is looking good! =]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This works for me. Don't ask me why I have to use the ORDER BY (didn't work without it).

```
SELECT name, continent,
   CASE WHEN continent='Oceania' THEN 'Australasia'
        WHEN continent =  'Eurasia' THEN 'Europe/Asia'
        WHEN name='Turkey' THEN 'Europe/Asia'
        WHEN continent='Caribbean' AND name LIKE 'B%' THEN 'North America'
        WHEN continent='Caribbean' AND name NOT LIKE 'B%' THEN 'South America'
        ELSE continent END
FROM world ORDER BY name
```

Comment: Yes, it looks like the dataset does contain `Eurasia`, so this is correct. I don't believe the ORDER BY is necessary since this corrects the `Eurasia` issue in OPs answer.

Comment: The `ORDER BY` is necessary to make the site work, not to answer the this interpretation of the question.

Answer (score 3):

Looks to be a bug in their system unless I'm reading the question wrong:

```
SELECT name, continent,
CASE WHEN continent='Oceania' THEN 'Australasia'
        WHEN continent IN ('Eurasia') THEN 'Europe/Asia'
        WHEN name='Turkey' THEN 'Europe/Asia'
        WHEN continent='Caribbean' AND name LIKE 'B%' THEN 'North America'
        WHEN continent='Caribbean' AND name NOT LIKE 'B%' THEN 'South America'
        ELSE continent END
FROM world
order by name
```

If you add in "order by name" it gives a correct answer with the above query. However, if you do not include the order by it marks it as incorrect. As to why I am not sure.

Answer (score 3):

The code below should solve your problem :

```
SELECT name AS Country, continent as Continent,
   CASE WHEN continent='Oceania' THEN 'Australasia'
        WHEN continent = 'Eurasia' THEN 'Europe/Asia'
WHEN name='Turkey' THEN 'Europe/Asia'
        WHEN continent='Caribbean' AND name LIKE 'B%' THEN 'North America'
        WHEN continent='Caribbean' AND name NOT LIKE 'B%' THEN 'South America'
        ELSE continent END AS "New Continent"
FROM world
WHERE tld IN ('.ag','.ba','.bb','.ca','.cn','.nz','.ru','.tr','.uk')
ORDER BY Country;
```

Answer (score 2):

This also works. Used an OR statement for Turkey and renamed new column

```
SELECT name,continent,
CASE 
WHEN continent='Oceania' THEN 'Australasia'
WHEN continent='Eurasia' OR name = 'Turkey' THEN 'Europe/Asia'
WHEN continent='Caribbean' AND name LIKE 'B%' THEN 'North America'
WHEN continent='Caribbean' AND name NOT LIKE 'B%' THEN 'South America'
ELSE continent 
END as 'new continent name'
FROM world 
ORDER BY name
```

Answer (score 2):

The order should not matter, but the website's answer (when you answer incorrectly) suggests that the output should be ordered by country name.

```
SELECT name AS Country, continent as Continent,
   CASE WHEN continent='Oceania' THEN 'Australasia'
        WHEN continent IN ('Eurasia', 'Turkey') THEN 'Europe/Asia'
        WHEN continent='Caribbean' AND name LIKE 'B%' THEN 'North America'
        WHEN continent='Caribbean' AND name NOT LIKE 'B%' THEN 'South America'
        ELSE continent END AS "New Continent"
FROM world
ORDER BY Country;
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried it, and using `'OR'` for Turkey instead of making new statement won't help itself.
Agree that this is not correct and is probably an error of the page `sqlzoo`.

But when used with `'ORDER BY name'` both ways are correct.

And the names of columns are not important, you can name them 'as YouLikeItToBe'.
So obviously, `sqlzoo` checks what is in the table, count and the order of it as well, however, doesn't keep the order.